# Hbase thrift2 python client API invalid

Tags: python, hbase, thrift

I am write a python script to load data from hbase. But things seem to goes wrong in `thrift` generated files. Here is my code:

```
def create_hbase_connection():
    thrift_socket = TSocket.TSocket(thrift_server, thrift_port)
    thrift_socket.setTimeout(thrift_timeout)
    thrift_transport = TTransport.TFramedTransport(thrift_socket)
    thrift_protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolAccelerated(thrift_transport)
    thrift_client = THBaseService.Client(thrift_protocol)
    try:
        thrift_transport.open()
    except Exception as e:
        print "connect to hbase thrift failed. (%s)" % e
        sys.exit()

    return thrift_protocol, thrift_client

def fetch_rows_from_hbase(thrift_protocol, thrift_client, start_row = None):
    tscan = ttypes.TScan()
    if start_row != None:
        tscan.startRow = start_row
    tscan.maxVersions = max_versions
    tscan.filterString = "FamilyFilter(!=, 'binary:ge')"
    scan_id = thrift_client.openScanner(hbase_table_name, tscan)
    result = thrift_client.getScannerRows(scan_id, row_limits + 1)
    print result
    print "=================================================\n"
    thrift_client.closeScanner(scan_id)
    thrift_protocol.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thrift_protocol, thrift_client = create_hbase_connection()
    fetch_rows_from_hbase(thrift_protocol, thrift_client)
```

And here is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./load_hbase.py", line 46,
>   in 
>       fetch_rows_from_hbase(thrift_protocol, thrift_client)   File "./load_hbase.py", line 37, in fetch_rows_from_hbase
>       scan_id = thrift_client.openScanner(hbase_table_name, tscan)   File "/home/lishaohua/kpn/load_hbase/thrift2/hbase/THBaseService.py",
>   line 715, in openScanner
>       return self.recv_openScanner()   File "/home/lishaohua/kpn/load_hbase/thrift2/hbase/THBaseService.py", line
>   735, in recv_openScanner
>       result.read(iprot)   File "/home/lishaohua/kpn/load_hbase/thrift2/hbase/THBaseService.py", line
>   3278, in read
>       fastbinary.decode_binary(self, iprot.trans, (self.**class**, self.thrift_spec)) AttributeError: 'TFramedTransport' object has no
>   attribute 'trans'

I check the code in `TTransport.py`, `TFramedTransport` has the attribute `self.__trans`. How to fix this? I can simply change `tans` to `__trans`, but there are more problems.

Answer (score 0):

I used `TBufferedTransport` instead of `TFramedTransport`, and it worked. You can try my solution below:

```
class ThriftConn(object):
    def __init__(self, ip, port, service_cls):
        self.socket = TSocket.TSocket(ip, port)
        self.trans = TTransport.TBufferedTransport(self.socket)                                                                                                                                                   
        self.protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(self.trans)
        self.client = service_cls.Client(self.protocol)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.trans.open()

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, 
        exception_traceback):
        self.trans.close()

HBASE_SERVER_CLIENT = ThriftConn(ip, port, THBaseService)
with HBASE_SERVER_CLIENT:
    scan = TScan()
    scan_id = HBASE_SERVER_CLIENT.client.openScanner(table, scan)
```